# Meteor push/browserhistory won't go/reload to new page

Tags: javascript, meteor, push

So i am trying to make it so when the user hit one of the profiles, they get pushed to the profile page of the user the click on.

I am using currently using this set of code:

```
const self = this;

    browserHistory.push({
        pathname: '/users/' + self.props.user.username,
        state: {_id: self.props.user._id}
    });
```

Which just enter the correct url in the url bar. Although, the page does not load/reload. So i manually have to reload the page to get into the userprofile

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Meteor creates *single page applications*, not traditional applications where every URL is served by an http server. You'll want to use a [router](https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html) for moving the user around your app. The recommended Meteor router is currently flow-router.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

You have to use a router which works properly with Meteor, right now [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) is the best option to go

Reloading the page is not the expected behavior when route changes in Meteor, only the content of the page should be change to match the new route. Because apps created by Meteor are [Single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), meaning that all content/code of your app are loaded at your first load.

After the first load, all required code for your app to work are already in client so when route changes the required content will be compute and put on the page, no request will be send to server.